# Android Update Widget Via button in Fragment or Activity

Tags: java, android, widget

I'm having a hard time understanding Widgets. All the tutorials I've done, I can update the widget directly via buttons on the widget themselves and that seems easy enough.

However, I can't find any full tutorials out there that show the process of updating a widget from a Fragment or Activity. I see a lot of partial codes for the provider class but not what to put in the fragment itself. I want to click a button in my Fragment, and send data over to the widget. Everything I've added, no change is every populated.

For example:

```
addToWidget.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Recipe recipes = new Recipe(0, "");
                String widgetName = recipes.getName();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("WidgetName", widgetName);
```

Here I save the name to my shared preferences and now I want to load that in the widget, but how do I get started with that? I've tried things with intents and remoteviews, but I just don't know what I'm doing honestly. I have a RecipeWidgetProvider.class, and recipe_widget_provider.xml and recipe_widget_provider_info.xml.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onUpdate method in the widget provider (anything you named it that extends from AppWidgetProvider) you retrieve your saved string and then you get your RemoteViews (the widget layout) like this:

```
 RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.name_of_your_layout);
            //then set the text like this
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.id_of_your_textview, sharedString);
```

The same code should work in your on button click so if it does not update immediately, you can use it there too. Just dont forget to add it in your Provider too or it will reset the text to default on you widget update.